# Apuntar a carpeta que se encuentra en el mismo directorio que mi archivo Jar

Tags: java, jar

alguien sabe como accedo a una carpeta que esta en la misma carpeta que me archivo Jar, se encuentra organizado de la siguiente manera:

```
   |__ Carpeta donde se encuentra el jar 
      |__ programa.jar 
      |__ IN
```

Dentro de IN se encuentran unos archivos que seran utilizados por el usuario, y necesito acceder a dicha carpeta, sin el uso de `JFileChooser`
Intente con `../IN/` Pero evidentemente no accede.
Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias maneras de obtenerlo, el primero es usando las propiedades de la clase System.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Directorio Actual = " +
              System.getProperty("user.dir"));
  }
}
```

El siguiente método es utilizar la clase Path, para obtener el directorio actual de trabajo:
import java.nio.file.Paths;

```
public void obtenerDirectorioActual(){
    String s = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString();
    System.out.println(s);
}
```